# Create database in flyway with Gradle

Tags: gradle, flyway

I'm very new to Gradle. I have a command `./gradlew clean build generateLocalProperties loadProperties flywayMigrate` and after it's executed, database was created from flyway.

I have another gradle command to execute cucumber tests.
It is `./gradlew cAAT`, I want to create database from `./gradlew cAAT` command without executing a separate Gradle command.

For that, I updated below Gradle task `copyAndDeployJobs`.

```
task copyAndDeployJobs {
    dependsOn loadProperties, copyConfigsToTalend, setupLocalJobDirectory, copyJobsToTalend, deployTalendJobs, **generateLocalProperties, loadProperties, flywayMigrate**
}
```

And I have added bolded part (**generateLocalProperties, loadProperties, flywayMigrate**) newly to the method. Now `./gradlew cAAT` is being executed successfully, but still, there is no database created after that.

Could you please someone help me to sort out this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you run `./gradlew -m copyAndDeployJobs` for me?

Comment: I wanted to create flyway only from ./gradlew cAAT

Comment: Then can you do `./gradlew -m cAAT`?